# Alternative Laurent expansion of $1-e^{-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, laurent-series

I wonder if there is Laurent expansion of $f(x) = 1 - e^{-x}$ where $x>0$, is real number.

It is known that the expansion :
$$ g(x) = 1- e^{-x} = x - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} - ... $$
for $ - \infty < x < \infty $

Originally function $f(x) \in (0,1)$ is bounded in $(0, \infty)$, however, the sum of the initial segment of $g(x)$ seems oscillatory too much as $x$ goes up, against that $f'(x) = e^{-x}$ trends to $0$ (I know that it may strictly make little sense, Anyway). So it makes me think whether or not there exist a Laurent expansion of $f(x)$ in any chance.

This is to find that 
$$
f(x) = c + \sum_{i=1} ^{\infty} a_i (x-w_0)^ {-i} + b_i (x-w_0)^i
$$
where all of $a_i$ are not $0$, $c,w_0,b_i$ is real.

Comment: Laurent expansions are unique. So, if a function is analytic (as is the case for $f$), then its Taylor expansion will equal its Laurent expansion. So, no, we must have all the $a_i = 0$.

Comment: All right, thanks

Comment: There is one Laurent series per annulus of analyticity. $1-e^{-z}$ is analytic on the whole complex plane so its annulus of analyticity are of the form $\{ z,|z-a|\in [0,\infty)\}$ and its Laurent series at $a$ is of course its Taylor series.

Comment: this helps a lot Thanks.